# how to detect if stop loading page button has been pressed before the form submissıon completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to detect if the button pressed while submissıon in progress

[image]

Comment: There's not going to be a simple resolution.  Try/Catch and validate your model on the back-end or I suppose you could roll the dice on onunload or something.  But don't validate client-side.  What happens when you Alt + F4, unplug the PC, hold the power button on the PC, etc?

Comment: my problem is in client side while the client upload some file there is a loader showing up what means the page busy , but the if the client cancels the submıssıon. i need to hide the loader

Comment: Very interesting question. I would like to know the answer to it! You probably won't track the event itself when this button is clicked, but you can try "fiddling" with `popstate` and `document.readyState`. -------> https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState

Comment: When pressed, all pending requests are canceled which is rejected as an error so you should check/catch error in fetch/ajax function and if there is error, remove busy state.